# XMLHttpRequest multiple value

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I have a form with many fields. when changing the value of a select I would like to update various elements. How do I populate more input?

this is my function

```
//PRODUCT LANG
    function product_lang(id) {
        //VARIABLE
        var product_lang= $("#lang").val();
        var product_id= id; 

        var method = 'get'  
        var param = 'id='+product_id+'&lang='+product_lang+'&data=lang';
        var page = adminfolder+'resource/product/product_request.php';

        var url=page+"?"+param;
        var http=new XMLHttpRequest();   
        http.open(method, url , true);
        var result="";
        http.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (http.readyState==4 || http.readyState=="complete"){
                if (http.status == 200){
                    result=http.responseText;
                    $('#productname').val(result);
                }
            }
        }
        http.send(null);     
    }
```

product_request.php

```
require_once("../../session.php");

$product_id=$_GET['id'];
$product_lang=$_GET['lang'];

if ($_GET['data']=="lang") {
    $sql="SELECT * from xxx where product_id=".$product_id." and lang=".$product_lang." ";
    foreach( $db->query($sql) as $row ){
        $result=1;
    }

    if ($result==1){
        echo $row['name']; 
    }
}
```

from my function I go to populate only one field

from the query I would like to populate more fields

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. it's correct?

in function

```
result = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
$('#productname').val(result[0]);
```

in php

```
$result = array($row['name'], $row['seo_title']);
echo json_encode($result);
```